# Ansible dynamic inventory getting IP address

Tags: azure, ansible, jinja2

I am building a number of servers in Azure via Ansible. I am trying to subsequently configure prometheus to monitor those servers.

However I can't figure out how to get the IP address out of the dynamic inventory for each server that's created.

I've been through a number of variations, this shows what I'm looking for

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
      - targets: ['{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}']
        labels: {'host': '{{ host }}' }
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously this just prints the local vm that it is running on. But I've no clue what to put there for the IP of the 'host'

Comment: `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}` => `{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}`

Comment: @Zeitounator that wasn't at all obvious! (/s) - thank you kindly - if you want to make it an answer for some juicy internet points...

Comment: Debug the content of `hostvars` to see its structure and the one of `host` in your loop, as well as `ìnventory_hostname`, and it suddenly becomes crystal clear :) Probably worth a read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables